# How to extract only the year from a date string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to grab only the first four characters of a date string from an API in JavaScript?

### Back story

I am using The Movie Database, which allows me to get the exact release dates of movies. For instances, I get the following object of data for "Finding Nemo":

[image]

I've added the following code in my Movies.js component, `<p>({movie.release_date})</p>`
and it returns 2003-05-30 as expected.

But is there a way to extract only the first four characters (2003) and return only that? Or better yet, is there a way to extract only the release year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [substring](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) function on a string, providing the character to start with (0 is the first, like an array) and how many characters to grab.

```js
const date = "2020-01-01";

const year = date.substring(0, 4);

alert(year);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can do this, each method is fairly similar. The below are fairly simple and straight forward to use.

#### Split at '-'

```js
const date = "2020-01-01";
const year = date.split("-")[0];

alert(year);
```

This method separates the string where ever there is a '-' and stores each section in an array. You want the first section, the one located in the first spot or with an index of 0. This is probably the easiest and most straight forward method, you can learn more about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-string-prototype-split-function/)

#### Slice method

```js
const date = "2020-01-01";
const year = date.slice(0, 4);

alert(year);
```

This method works by slicing the characters from an index of 0 to an index of 4 off of the string returning them in the constant year.

#### Substr method

This method was already referenced in this thread by @larz so I won't bother adding an example or explaining it as they can be found in their answer.

I hope this helps, for more information or you want to explore more methods take a look at [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve extracting only the release year in the following way

```
const d = new Date( movie.release_date );
d.getFullYear();
```